# Failing to start bash script as a service | Thanos - Prometheus

Tags: linux, ubuntu, prometheus, autostart, thanos

I am feeling like I tried everything but still failing. I am trying to make a cluster of Thanos, Prometheus, and Grafana. I wrote a script that works like a charm in the terminal but fails to start as a service `systemd`. My environment is:

1. `Ubuntu 20.04.2`
2. `Docker 20.10.5`

[And my file dependencies are this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8u24.png)

### This is my script content:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to build monitoring cluster with Thanos support.
# Actions: deploy | destroy
#
#
# Usage: ./setup deploy [ prom|sidecar|querier|grafana|all ]  | destroy [prom|sidecar|querier|grafana|volume|network|all]
#
#set -x
# Params

#*******************************************************************************************************#

action="$1"
component="$2"

#*******************************************************************************************************#

#---------------------------------Creating volumes for persistant data storage--------------------------#
create_volume() {
echo "--> Creating persistent volumes for prometheus servers"
for item in 1 2 3
do
    mkdir -p $(pwd)/prometheusStorage$item
done
}
#---------------------------------------End of creating-------------------------------------------------#

#*******************************************************************************************************#

#----------------------------------------Creating docker network----------------------------------------#
create_docker_network() {
docker network create thanos &> /dev/null
}
#----------------------------------------End of creating network----------------------------------------#

#*******************************************************************************************************#

#----------------------------------------Deploying prometheus instances---------------------------------#
deploy_prom() {
echo "--> Deploying prometheus instances"
for item in 1 2 3
do
    echo "--> Deploying prometheus instance #$item"
    docker run -d --net=thanos --rm -v $(pwd)/prometheus0$item.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml -p 909$item:909$item -v $(pwd)/prometheusStorage$item:/prometheus -u root --name prometheus0$item  quay.io/prometheus/prometheus  \
    --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
    --storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus \
    --web.listen-address=:909$item \
    --web.enable-lifecycle \
    --storage.tsdb.retention.time=5d \
    --storage.tsdb.min-block-duration=5m \
    --storage.tsdb.max-block-duration=5m \
    --web.enable-admin-api &> /dev/null
    sleep 3
done
#-------------------------------->Checking for launched Prometheus containers
curl http://localhost:9091 &> /dev/null
prom01=$?
sleep 1
curl http://localhost:9092 &> /dev/null
prom02=$?
sleep 1
curl http://localhost:9093 &> /dev/null
prom03=$?
sleep 1
 if [[ prom01 -eq 0 && prom02 -eq 0 && prom03 -eq 0 ]] ; then
     echo "--> Prometheus 01, 02 ,03 got deployed on 9091,9092,9093 port respectively"
 else
     echo "--> Error occurred while deploying prometheus server"
     exit 1
 fi
echo "*"
#------------------------------->End of checking
}
#----------------------------------------End of deploying instances-------------------------------------#

#*******************************************************************************************************#

#----------------------------------------Deploying sidecar instances------------------------------------#
deploy_sidecar() {
if [ ! -d "$(pwd)/object-storage" ]; then
    mkdir object-storage
fi
echo "--> Deploying thanos sidecar for each prometheus instance in the cluster"
for item in 1 2 3
do
    echo "--> Deploying sidecar for prometheus instance #$item"
    docker run -d --rm --net=thanos -v $(pwd)/prometheus0$item.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml -v $(pwd)/bucket_config.yaml:/tmp/bucket_config.yaml --name prometheus0$item-sidecar -u root \
        -v $(pwd)/prometheusStorage$item:/tmp/prometheusStorage \
        -v $(pwd)/object-storage:/object-storage \
        quay.io/thanos/thanos:main-2021-03-22-d173bcb9  sidecar \
        --http-address 0.0.0.0:1909$item \
        --grpc-address 0.0.0.0:1919$item \
        --reloader.config-file /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
        --prometheus.url http://prometheus0$item:909$item \
        --tsdb.path /tmp/prometheusStorage \
        --objstore.config-file /tmp/bucket_config.yaml &> /dev/null
SCRC=$?
    sleep 3
done
echo "--> Using Local volume as a object storage"
if [ $SCRC -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "--> All sidecars got deployed successfully for all prometheus instances"
else
    echo "--> Error while deploying sidecars"
    exit 1
fi
echo "*"
}
#----------------------------------------End of deploying instances-------------------------------------#

#*******************************************************************************************************#

#----------------------------------------Deploying querier instances------------------------------------#
deploy_querier(){
docker run -d --rm --net=thanos --name thanos-querier -p 29090:29090 quay.io/thanos/thanos:main-2021-03-22-d173bcb9 query \
    --http-address 0.0.0.0:29090 \
    --query.replica-label replica \
    --store prometheus01-sidecar:19191 \
    --store prometheus02-sidecar:19192 \
    --store prometheus03-sidecar:19193 &> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "--> Deployed thanos querier component"
else
    echo "--> Error while deploying thanos querier component"
    exit 1
fi
echo "*"
}
#----------------------------------------End of deploying instance--------------------------------------#

#*******************************************************************************************************#

#--------------------------------------------Deploying grafana------------------------------------------#
deploy_grafana() {
        echo "--> Deploying single instance of grafana"
    docker run -d --name grafana --net=thanos -p 3000:3000 quay.io/bitnami/grafana:latest &> /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "--> Grafana is up and running on 3000 port"
    else
        echo "--> Error while deploying grafana"
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "*"
    echo "--> Cluster is up and running"
}
#--------------------------------------------End of deploying grafana-----------------------------------#

#*******************************************************************************************************#



case "$action" in
deploy)
    case "$component" in
        prom)
            # preparing persistance volumes.
            create_volume
            # creating a namespace for docker
            create_docker_network
            # deploying prometheuse server:
            echo "*"
            deploy_prom
        ;;
sidecar)
            deploy_sidecar
        ;;
querier)
            # Deploying thanos querier which queries the thanos side car endpoint over gRPC
            deploy_querier
        ;;
        grafana)
            # deploy grafana instance
            deploy_grafana
        ;;
all)
            create_volume
            create_docker_network
            deploy_prom
            deploy_sidecar
            deploy_querier
            deploy_grafana
        ;;
        *)
            echo "Choose an component to deploy from prom|sidecar|querier|grafana|all"
            exit 1
        ;;
    esac
;;
destroy)
    case "$component" in
        prom)
            for container in prometheus01 prometheus02 prometheus03
            do
                echo "--> Removing $container residue."
                docker container stop $container &> /dev/null
            done
            sleep 3
            docker network ls | grep thanos &> /dev/null
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "--> Removing docker network [thanos]"
                docker network rm thanos &> /dev/null
            fi
        ;;
sidecar)
            for container in prometheus01-sidecar prometheus02-sidecar prometheus03-sidecar
            do
                echo "--> Removing $container residue."
                docker container stop $container &> /dev/null
            done
        ;;
querier)
            echo "--> Removing querier residue."
            docker container stop thanos-querier &> /dev/null
        ;;
grafana)
            echo "--> Removing grafana residue."
            docker container stop grafana &> /dev/null
            docker ps -a | grep grafana &>/dev/null
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                docker rm -f grafana &> /dev/null
            fi
        ;;
volume)
           for item in prometheusStorage1 prometheusStorage2 prometheusStorage3 object-storage
            do
                if [ -d "$item" ]; then
                    echo "--> Deleting mounted storage volume: $item"
                    rm -rf $item
                fi
            done
        ;;
network)
           docker network ls | grep thanos &> /dev/null
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "--> Removing docker network [thanos]"
                docker network rm thanos &> /dev/null
            fi
        clear
        ;;                      
all)
            for container in prometheus01 prometheus02 prometheus03 prometheus01-sidecar prometheus02-sidecar prometheus03-sidecar thanos-querier grafana
            do
                docker ps | grep $container &> /dev/null
                UPRC=$?
                if [ "$UPRC" -eq 0 ]; then
                    for container in prometheus01 prometheus02 prometheus03 prometheus01-sidecar prometheus02-sidecar prometheus03-sidecar thanos-querier grafana
                    do
                        echo "--> Removing $container residue"
                        docker container stop $container &> /dev/null
                    done
                    CONTAINERRC=$?
                    if [ "$CONTAINERRC" -eq 0 ]; then
                        docker ps -a | grep grafana | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker rm -f &>/dev/null
                        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                            docker rm -f grafana &> /dev/null
                        fi
                        echo "*"
                        echo "--> All containers drained out"
                    else
                        echo "--> Error while stopping grafana container"
                        exit 1
                    fi
else
                    CLUSTERDOWN=yes
                fi
            done
            docker network ls | grep thanos &> /dev/null
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "--> Removing docker network [thanos]"
                docker network rm thanos &> /dev/null
            fi
            if [ ! -z "$CLUSTERDOWN" ]; then
                echo "--> Cluster is already down, nothing to tear off"
                exit 0
            fi
;;
*)
            echo "Choose an component to destroy from prom|sidecar|querier|grafana|all"
            exit 1
        ;;
    esac
;;
*)
    echo "Usage: $0 deploy [ prom|sidecar|querier|grafana|all ] | destroy [ prom|sidecar|querier|grafana|all ]"
    exit 1
;;
esac
```

### And this is my `systemd` service

```
[Unit]
Description=ethtool script

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/setup.sh deploy all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The problem is, if script starts as a service it fails to to run prometheus docker image but if I run it from terminal it works like charm. Other images runs normally. I don't know where is the problem.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance

### Edit

---

### Shellcheck output

```
$ shellcheck myscript
 
Line 23:
        mkdir -p $(pwd)/prometheusStorage$item
                 ^-- SC2046: Quote this to prevent word splitting.
 
Line 44:
        docker run -d --net=thanos --rm -v $(pwd)/prometheus0$item.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml -p 909$item:909$item -v $(pwd)/prometheusStorage$item:/prometheus -u root --name prometheus0$item  quay.io/prometheus/prometheus  \
                                           ^-- SC2046: Quote this to prevent word splitting.
>>                                                                                                                            ^-- SC2046: Quote this to prevent word splitting.
 
Line 87:
        docker run -d --rm --net=thanos -v $(pwd)/prometheus0$item.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml -v $(pwd)/bucket_config.yaml:/tmp/bucket_config.yaml --name prometheus0$item-sidecar -u root \
                                           ^-- SC2046: Quote this to prevent word splitting.
>>                                                                                                       ^-- SC2046: Quote this to prevent word splitting.
 
Line 88:
                -v $(pwd)/prometheusStorage$item:/tmp/prometheusStorage \
                   ^-- SC2046: Quote this to prevent word splitting.
 
Line 89:
                -v $(pwd)/object-storage:/object-storage \
                   ^-- SC2046: Quote this to prevent word splitting.
 
Line 121:
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
     ^-- SC2181: Check exit code directly with e.g. 'if mycmd;', not indirectly with $?.
 
Line 137:
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
             ^-- SC2181: Check exit code directly with e.g. 'if mycmd;', not indirectly with $?.
 
Line 199:
                        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                             ^-- SC2181: Check exit code directly with e.g. 'if mycmd;', not indirectly with $?.
 
Line 219:
                        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                             ^-- SC2181: Check exit code directly with e.g. 'if mycmd;', not indirectly with $?.
 
Line 234:
                        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                             ^-- SC2181: Check exit code directly with e.g. 'if mycmd;', not indirectly with $?.
 
Line 241:
                        for container in prometheus01 prometheus02 prometheus03 prometheus01-sidecar prometheus02-sidecar prometheus03-sidecar thanos-querier grafana
                        ^-- SC2167: This parent loop has its index variable overridden.
 
Line 246:
                                        for container in prometheus01 prometheus02 prometheus03 prometheus01-sidecar prometheus02-sidecar prometheus03-sidecar thanos-querier grafana
                                        ^-- SC2165: This nested loop overrides the index variable of its parent.
 
Line 254:
                                                if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                                                     ^-- SC2181: Check exit code directly with e.g. 'if mycmd;', not indirectly with $?.
 
Line 268:
                        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                             ^-- SC2181: Check exit code directly with e.g. 'if mycmd;', not indirectly with $?.
 
Line 272:
                        if [ ! -z "$CLUSTERDOWN" ]; then
                             ^-- SC2236: Use -n instead of ! -z.
```

Here is error message when I start a service:

```
Mar 24 11:16:06 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: ++ pwd
Mar 24 11:16:06 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: + docker run -d --net=thanos --rm -v //prometheus02.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml -p 9091:9091 -v //prometheusStorage1:/prometheus -u root --name prometheus01 quay.io/prometheus/prometheus --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus --web.listen-address=:9091 --web.enable-lifecycle --storage.tsdb.retention.time=5d --storage.tsdb.min-block-duration=5m --storage.tsdb.max-block-duration=5m --web.enable-admin
Mar 24 11:16:06 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: + sleep 3
Mar 24 11:16:09 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: + for item in 1 2 3
Mar 24 11:16:09 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: + echo '--> Deploying prometheus instance #3'
Mar 24 11:16:09 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: --> Deploying prometheus instance #3
Mar 24 11:16:09 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: ++ pwd
Mar 24 11:16:09 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: ++ pwd
Mar 24 11:16:09 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: + docker run -d --net=thanos --rm -v //prometheus03.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml -p 9091:9091 -v //prometheusStorage1:/prometheus -u root --name prometheus01 quay.io/prometheus/prometheus --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus --web.listen-address=:9091 --web.enable-lifecycle --storage.tsdb.retention.time=5d --storage.tsdb.min-block-duration=5m --storage.tsdb.max-block-duration=5m --web.enable-admin
Mar 24 11:16:09 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: + docker run -d --net=thanos --rm -v //prometheus03.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml -p 9091:9091 -v //prometheusStorage1:/prometheus -u root --name prometheus01 quay.io/prometheus/prometheus --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus --web.listen-address=:9091 --web.enable-lifecycle --storage.tsdb.retention.time=5d --storage.tsdb.min-block-duration=5m --storage.tsdb.max-block-duration=5m --web.enable-admin
Mar 24 11:16:10 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: + sleep 3
Mar 24 11:16:13 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: + curl http://localhost:9091
Mar 24 11:16:13 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: + prom01=7
Mar 24 11:16:13 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: + sleep 1
Mar 24 11:16:14 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: + curl http://localhost:9092
Mar 24 11:16:14 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: + prom02=7
Mar 24 11:16:14 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: + sleep 1
Mar 24 11:16:14 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: + sleep 1
Mar 24 11:16:15 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: + curl http://localhost:9093
Mar 24 11:16:15 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: + prom03=7
Mar 24 11:16:15 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: + sleep 1
Mar 24 11:16:16 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: + [[ prom01 -eq 0 ]]
Mar 24 11:16:16 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: + echo '--> Error occurred while deploying prometheus server'
Mar 24 11:16:16 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: --> Error occurred while deploying prometheus server
Mar 24 11:16:16 thanos_server setup.sh[5386]: + exit 1
Mar 24 11:16:16 thanos_server systemd[1]: monitoring.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FA
Mar 24 11:16:16 thanos_server systemd[1]: monitoring.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Please add more details about "it fails to to run prometheus docker image". Do you get an error message? You might have to remove the output redirection `&> /dev/null` to see error messages. If you get an error message, copy&paste it to your question. (You can [edit] your question.) Paste your script at shellcheck.net and fix the errors. I don't know if the errors are related to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I added some more information, hope it will help to find out the problem

Comment: Instead of showing the shellcheck output you should try to fix the problems. The suggestion to use quotes SC2046 will be relevant if there are spaces in the result. The overriding of loop variables SC2167 means that you should use different variables in nested loops. You have two nested loops `for container in ...`, both using the variable `container`. The main point is **not to redirect the output to `/dev/null`**. You won't see errors reported by the `docker` or `curl` commands. You could redirect to a log file instead. My guess is that `$(pwd)` is not what you expect, resulting in an error.

Comment: Sorry for late reply but I solved problem by rewriting $(pwd) to absolute path of file

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with that was about `$(pwd)`. I don't know why exactly it happened, but when I changed `$(pwd)` with `absolute path` of file

Comment: Apparently, when your script is run as a service the current working directory is not the same as when you run it manually. If you assumed that `$(pwd)` is the same as the location of the script, then this assumption is wrong. It is independent from the script location. The initial working directory of your script's process is controlled by the process that starts your script. To get the location of your script you can process `$0`, e.g. `scriptdir="$0"` `scriptdir="${scriptdir%/*}"`. Note that this can be a relative directory specification, e.g. `.`.